# BTC that i received 2 days ago are missing, how come?

Tags: blockchain, breadwallet

I received 0.8 BTC 2 days ago, transaction was confirmed and i saw the money in my wallet, now i just log in to my wallet and the money dispersed include the confirmation from my transactions history. What that means? PLEASE HELP.

Transaction ID is:1CbZ3neNZxgfXzgswQpWJuHLGxMDQBaSVq

Comment: what wallet software/service do you use?

Comment: What do you mean with "dispersed"? The money has not been moved from the address you referenced: https://blockchain.info/address/1CbZ3neNZxgfXzgswQpWJuHLGxMDQBaSVq

Comment: Bread wallet and now all of my previews transactions "in process" after all of them was "complete".

Comment: 1CbZ3neNZxgfXzgswQpWJuHLGxMDQBaSVq - this is was my previews address for the 0.8 transaction. After i got the money obviously its change to a new one but now when i opened my wallet my receive address is again - 1CbZ3neNZxgfXzgswQpWJuHLGxMDQBaSVq.

Comment: @goralin try opening bread, going into settings, and select 'sync blockchain'. I checked a block explorer website and your 1CbZ3.. address appears to still have the ~0.8btc residing in it, so I'm guessing your software just needs to resync with the chain

Comment: Thanks Chytrik, i on a sync process for 4 hours already. do you know how much time usually its take?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe someone was monitoring your bitcoin wallet. You should enable 2 factor authentication to increase the security of your wallet. Furthermore, some transaction needs at least 3 confirmations before the proposed money enter your bitcoin wallet finally. Some scammers may use this method to collect money from their victims and cancel the transaction before all confirmations were made.  So please be careful.

Comment: From the comments in the OP you can see that it was a problem with his wallet software. The funds were not stolen.